# How to include NuGet packages "build" folder when using git with TFS

Tags: git, visual-studio-2013, tfs, gitignore

I'm new to git and am using it with TFS and Visual Studio 2013.

I want downloaded NuGet packages to be included in Git source control.

As an example, I've added a package System.Data.SQLite.Core.1.0.99.0 which includes files such as:

```
lib\net20\System.Data.SQLite.dll
lib\net35\System.Data.SQLite.dll
...
build\net20\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll
build\net20\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
```

The files under `packages\...\lib` are included in source control, which is what I want.

But the files under `packages\...\build` are **not** included.

How can I achieve this?
The .gitignore file provided by Visual Studio 2013 includes the following lines:

```
# Build results

...
[Rr]elease/
x64/
build/
...

# Enable "build/" folder in the NuGet Packages folder since NuGet packages use it for MSBuild targets
!packages/*/build/
```

which if I've read it right is

- excluding a number of output folders including "build" and "x64",
- then explicitly enabling the `build` folder again when its under "packages" (the NuGet packages folder).

I've tried editing .gitignore in a number of ways, including adding:

```
!**/packages/*/build/
!**/packages/*/build/*/x64
```

but nothing I've tried works.  Any tips appreciated.

**UPDATE**

I've found something that works.

In fact my git repository contains several VS solutions in subfolders.  So in fact the path to my packages folder is:

```
root/folder1/folder2/packages
```

where "root" is the root directory of my GIT repository, the directory that contains .gitignore.

I can get it to work by adding the lines:

```
!*/*/packages/*/build/
!*/*/packages/*/build/*/x64
```

This is a workaround, but what I really want is to be able to enable `packages/*/build` and `packages/*/build/*/x64` wherever they appear in the folder hierarchy.  Prefixing with "**" does not work.

To repro this:

- Create a subfolder in a git repository
- Create a Visual Studio 2013 solution in this subfolder
- Use NuGet to add the package "System.Data.SQLite Core (x86/x64)" to the solution.

Comment: You should not put binaries into a Git repository -- Git does not effectively version binaries, and it leads to significant bloat and can cause severe repository performance problems over time when cloning and checking out branches. If you have to put binaries into Git for some reason, use Git LFS.

Comment: @DanielMann thanks for the advice, but I've considered the tradeoffs and still want to store the binaries (a small number of binaries which are part of a NuGet package and will never change).  I don't believe our inhouse TFS Git server has LFS support.

Comment: It would be nice if the downvoter would explain what I can do to improve this question

Answer (score 0):

To include all the files in the packages folder add the following:

```
!packages/*
```

Comment: I've tried that and it doesn't work.  What did work was to temporarily comment out the two lines "x64/" and "build/".  The files then appear in VS2013 as untracked files and I can check them in and push them to the server.  Subsequently I undo the change to .gitignore.  This is obviously not a satisfactory workaround.

Comment: I ran through this scenario on my local machine and found I need to add "!packages/*" for git to include all files under packages, including the "packages/build" folder.

Comment: Maybe VS is caching the gitignore file.  Did you restart after making the change?

Comment: I don't think it can be caching the .gitignore file, because if I comment out the two lines "x64/" and "build/", then the files appear in VS2013 as untracked files.  I have tried restarting after making the changes and it made no difference.

Comment: see update to question for more info including a workaround

Answer (score 0):

Delete "ms-persist.xml" file in ".git" folder of your project and then try again.

Comment: @Joe Can you run "git config --list --global" command to check if you have global gitignore file?

Comment: the output from the command was values for user.name and user.email - nothing about a global gitignore file